# Are truncate and raw mutually exclusive methods in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, truncate, html-safe

I am trying to do this `truncate raw(@some_text), length: 300` . When the text exceeds the limit of 300 characters I see html tags in the text.

I need to truncate and implement html(tags prepended and appended) properties in the text. Is there any other way to do the same? 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work raw(@some_text.slice(0,300))

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is by truncating you'll be removing the closing tags.  You're basically going to need to strip all the tags if you need to truncate it.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this to both truncate and remove html tags from the text....

truncate(strip_tags(@some_text), :length => 300)

[Reference Link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-strip_tags)

Comment: this makes text to lose it's html properties. i.e tags that preceed or succeed text should be implemented and truncated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's code we use for this:

```
#app/helpers/application_helper.rb
def clean(content, length)
    body = sanitize(content, tags: [])
    truncate(body, length: length, separator: " ")
end
```

If you put that into a helper, you can call: `clean(@some_text, "300")`